# Changing content through history.pushState

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have made a template that I would like to load in using jQuery .load() function. When testing I found out that it won't load any .

Here is my load code:

```
    function open() {

            history.pushState(null, null, "artiesten.php?u=user2");

            $('.content').load('artiest_template.php .content');

        }
```

Here is my template code:

```
<?php include('includes/connect.php') ?>
    <span class="content">

    <div class="right_col" role="main">

    <div class="">
     <script>alert("nothing")</script>
      <?php 
      echo '<script>alert("' . $_GET['u'] . ' or nothing")</script>';
if($_GET['u']){
$t = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_GET['u']);
$res = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM artiesten WHERE Naam='" . $t . "'");
$i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo '
    <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".a-titel").html("' . $i['Titel'] . '");
       $(".a-naam").html("' . $i['Naam'] . '");
       $(".a-over").html("' . $i['Over'] . '");
       $(".a-kernmerk").html("' . $i['Kernmerk'] . '");
       $(".a-email").html("' . $i['Email'] . '");
       $(".a-foto").attr("src", "images/' . $i['Naam'] . '.jpg");
       history.pushState(null, null, "?u=' . $i['Naam'] . '");
    });
    </script>';
}
?>  



    </div>

    </div>

    </span>
```

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `.content` with the file path in your load function?

Comment: @DiddleDot so it will only load the specific thing I want to load instead of refreshing.

Comment: Waarom staat ".content" achteraan in load() ? ".content" maakt geen deel uit van de URL. Indien er andere parameters worden toegevoegd tot load() moeten ze gescheiden worden met een comma.

Comment: You'r calling `load()` on `$('.content')`. Which means the content will be loaded into all elements with the class `content`. The syntax is incorrect if you include `.content` where the path to the file you want to load should go. Look at JBoy's answer. That's how it should be written.

Comment: @PandaCrafter1 Als je het antwoord niet aanduidt als een oplossing krijgen de mensen die jou hebben geholpen geen punten.

Comment: @Kobbe I did mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
 function open() {

        history.pushState(null, null, "artiesten.php?u=Chato De Veirman");

        $('.content').load('artiest_template.php');

    }
```

not

```
  function open() {

        history.pushState(null, null, "artiesten.php?u=Chato De Veirman");

        $('.content').load('artiest_template.php .content');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery load() takes three parameters, URL, data and a function. These parameters have to be separated by a coma. Your load() has something behind your URL that is not part of the URL.

Change

```
$('.content').load('artiest_template.php .content');
```

to

```
$('.content').load('artiest_template.php');
```